# How to use values from a hashmap as text on separate fragments of an app?

Tags: java, android

My team and I are creating an app that displays menu options for breakfast, lunch, and dinner for today, tomorrow, and the whole week. We have the week menu put into a hashmap with the key being the day of the week. How can we display that string in the today tab, tomorrow tab, and week tab? I have included the code for the separate tabs and our main activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "Dining Hall Menu";
    private LinkedHashMap<String, String> menu = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    private SectionsPageAdapter mSectionsPageAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;


    public void readJsonStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
        try {
            readMessagesArray(reader);
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
    }

    public void readMessagesArray(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
        int count = 0;
        reader.beginArray();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            readMessage(reader, count);
            count++;
        }
        reader.endArray();
    }

    public void readMessage(JsonReader reader, int count) throws IOException {
        String day = null;
        String food = null;
        reader.beginObject();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            String name = reader.nextName();
            if (name.equals("Monday") || name.equals("Tuesday") || name.equals("Wednesday")
                    || name.equals("Thursday") || name.equals("Friday")
                    || name.equals("Saturday") || name.equals("Sunday")) {
                day = name;
                food = reader.nextString();
                if (count == 0) {
                    menu.put(day, food);
                } else if (count == 1) {
                    menu.put(day, menu.get(day) + food);
                } else {
                    menu.put(day, menu.get(day) + food);
                }
            } else {
                reader.skipValue();
            }
        }
        reader.endObject();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
            InputStream in = getAssets().open("Week11.json");
            readJsonStream(in);
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Starting");

        mSectionsPageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        setupViewPager(mViewPager);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
        setupTabIcons(tabLayout);

    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new Tab1Fragment(), "Today");
        adapter.addFragment(new Tab2Fragment(), "Tomorrow");
        adapter.addFragment(new Tab3Fragment(), "Week");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "Today";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_fragment, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return view;
    }
}

public class Tab2Fragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "Tomorrow";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2_fragment, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return view;
    }
}

public class Tab3Fragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "Week";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3_fragment, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to set variables directly on fragment classes since fragment lifecycle is controlled by the platform and may be destroyed and recreated any time the platform wills. This will probably cause a crash since your hashmap is not initialized when the platform creates a new instance of the fragment.

Comment: Also, please try a more standard approach such as a database to store the values and retrieve them in the fragment. A dedicated holder singleton class will also work. Put your values in a singleton holder class and retrieve in your fragments.